# Leiningen error creating new app on mac osx

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to use leiningen 2.3.2.

When I run:

```
lein new app my-stuff
```

the following error occours:

```
java.lang.Exception: project.clj must define project map
at leiningen.core.project$read.invoke(project.clj:681)
at leiningen.core.project$read.invoke(project.clj:685)
at leiningen.core.project$read.invoke(project.clj:686)
at leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__1332.invoke(main.clj:256)
at leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke(main.clj:252)
```

I used homebrew to install leiningen.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you might have a malformed project.clj in your current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alex noted in the comments, you have a deformed project.clj file in directory where you are executing Leiningen from. Removing the file will solve your problem.

You are probably assuming Leiningen creates the template files in the current directory, while in fact it will create a new one, in your case 'my-stuff'.